# tesseract ocr for php no response

Tags: php, tesseract

I am using tesseract-ocr-for-php and i have installed tesseract and add the path to my environment variable and it is working via command prompt but when i use it via php it is returning empty string.here is my code for the php

```
<?php

require_once '../src/TesseractOCR.php';

$filepath = "text.jpeg";

$tesseractInstance = new TesseractOCR($filepath);

$result = $tesseractInstance->run();

echo $result;

$x = exec("tesseract.exe test.png test");
echo $x;

$z = (new TesseractOCR($filepath))->run();
echo $z;

$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('text.jpeg');
$y = $tesseract->run();
echo $y;

var_dump($result);
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
var_dump($z);

?>
```

in all cases it is returning Empty string

```
C:\wamp64\www\tesseract\tests\test.php:40:string '' (length=0)
```

can anyone help me figure out where the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
    <?php
require_once("src/TesseractOCR.php");

$File_exe = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe";
$image = "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/testing.png";
$text = "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/out";
$output = exec("\"$File_exe\" \"$image\" \"$text\" "); //Stored the output in a text file I called "out"



$myfile = fopen("out.txt", "r","C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP") or die("No such file"); //Retrieving the output I stored in the text file(The text from the image)
echo fread($myfile,filesize("out.txt")); //Display to screen
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

To save the output in a variable first, simply equate the variable, e.g $x, to the fread(...), before you echo.

```
$x=fread($myfile,filesize("out.txt");
```